# How do i uninstall composer on Mac?

Tags: composer-php

I have installed [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) with this commands:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

How can i uninstall it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you ran `composer-setup.php` without any additional arguments it should be in a file called `composer.phar` in the directory where you ran those commands.

Delete that file and you're done.

Comment: This is a better answer: https://teamtreehouse.com/community/uninstalling-composer-on-macs

Comment: @AnaMariaCabrera, it depends how Composer was installed. OP ran the specific commands listed in the question, which resulted in a `composer.phar` file in their home directory. This file (probably) wouldn't be found with `which composer`.

Answer (score 30):

You followed instructions on the composer website and probably installed composer globally if so just use:

```
1.  cd usr/local/bin
2.  rm -r composer
```

If you have put composer somewhere else then find it first

```
1.  which composer
```

this will return the current path like `folder1/folder2/composer`and then the same steps:

```
1.  cd folder1/folder2
2.  rm -r composer
```

You also may want to delete rest of composer files. Simply go with:

```
1. cd /
2. cd Users/<hereYourUserName>
3. rm -r .composer
```