# Composer uninstall for a subdirectory project (Mac)

Tags: macos, terminal, composer-php

In a project, I have installed one composer in [this independent subdirectory](https://github.com/emarcier/usco/tree/master/master/cron/), and I have a **main composer** in [the main directory](https://github.com/emarcier/usco).

Now, I have set up the classmap of subdirectory composer in the **main composer**, which works. The subdirectory `composer.json` and other relevant composer files are not required anymore.

I'd like to correctly remove/uninstall only the subdirectory composer, maybe similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314254/how-do-i-uninstall-composer-on-mac).

`which composer` in both directories returns:

```
/usr/local/bin/composer
```

> What are the correct commands to remove a subdirectory composer, without accidentally removing the **main composer**? Or do I just manually do that?

Comment: You are referring to both the command and the `composer.json` files using composer, which makes it a bit difficult to understand what you want to do. Do I understand correctly, that basically you want to have only the main `composer.json`, but it should provide all dependencies, autoloading, etc. for the main project and the cron subdirectory?

Comment: In that case you can just manually remove both the file and folder. The `composer`-command only ever creates the vendor folder and the `composer.lock` and makes changes to the `composer.json`. When there is no `composer.json` the command will do nothing. If there is no vendor folder it will use the `composer.lock` to install the exact same versions of the dependencies in vendor/ or use `composer.json` to install the newest versions and then create a `composer.lock` with informations of which ones were installed.

Comment: Since vendor can safely be deleted and composer will install the same versions as before, when there is a `composer.lock` you do not have to check in the vendor folder in git (just add vendor/ to the `.gitignore` file). This will keep your repository smaller when you share it or check it out on a different machine and still keeps all the necessary version information, so you don't run into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer only ever creates/modifies 2 files and the vendor-folder in your project, `composer.json` and `composer.lock` from those 2 files it knows which dependencies to install into the vendor folder. Removing them is all you need to do.

You can safely delete the vendor folder and Composer will install the same versions of the dependencies when a `composer.lock` is present. If there is no `composer.lock` it works basically like a `composer update`, meaning it will install the newest versions and create a `composer.lock` for them.

If you remove all 3 then composer will not recognize what to do and tell you to create `composer.json` first. This is all you need to remove anything composer-related from a project.